# WebClient not sending Authorization Header to Web Service in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, asp.net-web-api, webclient, restful-authentication

Here is a situation with WebClient on Windows Phone.
I was able to pull & push data to web services hosted with asp.net Web Api.
Now I enabled basic authentication on Web services and on Windows Phone code added up Header to WebClient.
I notice that the authorization header is not reaching the web service and hence the web service throws bad request.
Have searched stackoverflow and blogs but couldn't get the authorization header to web service working.
Some direction on the above issue would be of great help.

Comment: Take a look at this question:- [not return correct post method result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632474/not-return-correct-post-method-result) i Think you have the same problem, even though you have to give us some more info.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason webclient is not sending the authorization header.

I have asked a windows phone champ from my network. He has advised to install nuget package HttpClient. And use HttpClient instead of WebClient. This HttpClient supports async and await even on wp7. Could get it working easily.

[nuget package for httpclient](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/2.2.18)

Sample Code:

```
string api = "/api/example/?id=abc";
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:0000/");

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue     
                                                  ("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String
                                                              (
                                                                  new Helpers().StringToAscii(Username, Password)      
                                                              )
                                                   );
var resultString = await client.GetStringAsync(api);
```

Hope this helps.